# How to create a HttpTrigger that will match any url?

Tags: c#, f#, azure-functions

I am writing an azure function where I want to be able to handle the routing based on the url as part of the implementation. I want to be able to catch any url regardless of number of segments.

Based on:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook-trigger?tabs=csharp#using-route-parameters

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2#constraints

I wrote the `Route` to accept up to 3 segments and can easily add more but I want to know if it's possible to just match any url?

```
[<FunctionName("MyFunction")>]
let myFunction
    (
        [<HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, Route = "{seg1?}/{seg2?}/{seg3?}")>] req: HttpRequest,
        log: ILogger,
        context: ExecutionContext
    ) =
    // Implementation
```

Note: Code is F# but should be equally applicable to C# and easy to adapt.

Comment: What happens if you do `Route = null` ?

Comment: `Route = null` is equivalent to `Route = <FunctionName>` i.e. will match exactly /api/MyFunction

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have discovered you can match anything with a `*` at the start of the parameter name `Route = "{*any}"` will match any url.